# Java JDBC Prepared Statement not inserting single quotes (SQL Escaping)

Tags: java

I have the following method to a person into the database which later is used to create a person object:

```
public static void addPerson(String personCode, String firstName, String lastName, 
        String phoneNo, String street, String city, String state, 
        String zip, String country) {
    Connection conn = database.com.airamerica.interfaces.DatabaseConnect.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps;
    ResultSet rs;
    String addAddressQuery = "INSERT INTO `Addresses` (`street`,`city`,`state`,`zip`,`country`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
    String checkAddress = "SELECT `address_ID` FROM `Addresses` WHERE street = ? AND city = ? AND state = ? AND zip = ? AND country = ?";
    String addPersonQuery = "INSERT INTO `Persons` (`personCode`,`firstName`,`lastName`,`address_ID`,`phoneNumber`) VALUES (?,?,?,(SELECT `address_ID` FROM `Addresses` WHERE street = ? AND city = ? AND state = ? AND zip = ? AND country = ?),?)";
    try
    {
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(checkAddress);
        ps.setString(1, street);
        ps.setString(2, city);
        ps.setString(3, state);
        ps.setString(4, zip);
        ps.setString(5, country);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        if(!(rs.next())){
            ps = conn.prepareStatement(addAddressQuery);
            ps.setString(1, street);
            ps.setString(2, city);
            ps.setString(3, state);
            ps.setString(4, zip);
            ps.setString(5, country);
            ps.executeUpdate();
            ps.close();
        }
        ps.close();
        rs.close();
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(addPersonQuery);
        ps.setString(1, personCode);
        ps.setString(2, firstName);
        ps.setString(3, lastName);
        ps.setString(4, street);
        ps.setString(5, city);
        ps.setString(6, state);
        ps.setString(7, zip);
        ps.setString(8, country);
        ps.setString(9, phoneNo);
        ps.executeUpdate();
        ps.close();
        conn.close();
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        System.out.println("SQLException: ");
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

The problem is when we insert a name like `Miles O'Brien` it gets inserted as `Miles O&apos;Brien` I tried to escape using a method to replace the single quote (apostrophe) with two of them ('') for escaping. That method just caused data to be inserted as `Miles O&apos;&apos;Brien`. How do we go about fixing this? The problem is at `ps.setString(3, lastName);` How do we get the last name into the database without it going in as `&apos;`?

just in case you need it the engine is InnoDB and we are using default UTF8 as the collation.

As you can see the last name is passed to the method as well.

Comment: This looks to me to be more of a problem with the web layer of your app than the database layer.  Are you sure that the your `addPerson` method is being called with `lastName` set to `O'Brien` rather than `O&apos;Brien`?  My suspicion is that this isn't the case, and that your web layer (of which you have provided no details), is doing the unwanted `O'Brien` to `O&apos;Brien` conversion, not the database.  I'm assuming you have a web layer, as I don't see where else an HTML entity would come from.

Comment: We don't have a web layer, this is all a console application, all our displays are pretty much just xml that we export or text files. It is a school program but we are stuck at this point. The passed name to the method is O'Brien and the prepared statement does say O'Brien when we step through the application but the database shows O&apos;Brein

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [GIGO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out)

A step debugger and a well placed break point or the following will show you that this is not related to JDBC at all.

*A step debugger is the much preferred way to inspect running code!*

```
public static void addPerson(final String personCode, final String firstName, final String lastName, 
                             final String phoneNo, final String street, final String city, final String state, 
                             final String zip, final String country) {

        System.out.println(String.format("Last Name = %s",lastName));

        // the rest of your code
}
```

Comment: When I did this lastName says O'Brien in the console but in the database it says O&apos;Brien

Comment: What *console*? If this is from some unit test or something else that is not valid, you need it to be in the logs from the server to tell what is actually going on.